# i got this error Execution failed for task :app:processDebugMainManifest while running with npm run android but with android studio it works fine

Tags: android, android-studio

> react-native run-android

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 870 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running. npm:load Completed in 18ms
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @5e15465d

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @5e15465d

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

```
at makeError (/Users/arbazshaikh/Desktop/authentication/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
at /Users/arbazshaikh/Desktop/authentication/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/arbazshaikh/Desktop/authentication/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/Users/arbazshaikh/Desktop/authentication/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

i don't know if its related to Mac M1 chip

Answer (score 2):

Finally i found solution for this.. My JDK version was 17. still don't know why JDK 17 gave error after sometime. Now i downgraded to JDK 14 and now works fine!!! Hope this helps

Comment: I was going to give a solution for this but you solved it. I think this happened because the  gradle version you're using can't support jdk 17.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: did you uninstall the jdk and install again? or did you have to change anything else? because im having the same issue, its a brand new project, i have JDK 17 and downloaded the latest version of gradle which, supposedly, supports JDK 17

Comment: @le0nicolas yess u have to uninstall jdk 17 & install jdk from this link i downloaded https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-11-lts&os=macos&architecture=arm-64-bit&package=jdk